# Installing VirtIO SCSI on Windows Guest fails

Tags: linux, windows, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm running Windows 10 as guest via KVM / qemu. Unfortunately, Windows doesn't recognize the fedora [virtio drivers](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers#Direct_download) I want to install for better HDD perfomance. The driver itself does show up, but installing it fails:

[Qemu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxIyB.png) - "No new device drivers found"

I tried several driver versions, namely `0.1.102`, `0.1.110` and `0.1.112`, all for amd64.

Commandline options:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci \
-drive if=none,id=hd,file=win.img,format=raw -device scsi-hd,drive=hd \
--enable-kvm \
-cdrom Win10_1511_German_x64.iso \
-m 4048 \
-drive file=$HOME/VirtualMachines/virtio-win-0.1.112.iso,id=driveriso,if=none,format=raw \
-device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=driveriso \
-cpu host,kvm=off
```

What could cause Win 10 to reject those drivers? Are there better alternatives for fast HDD access from the Guest OS?

Host OS:

- **CPU**: i7-6700k
- **OS**: Ubuntu 15.10
- **uname -r**: 4.3.4-040304-generic
- **uname -m**: x86_64
- **qemu-system-x86_64 --version**: QEMU emulator version 2.3.0 (Debian 1:2.3+dfsg-5ubuntu9.2)

Comment: I recommend strongly that you use `virt-manager` or `virt-install` with libvirtd to create VMs. Doing it manually can only result in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem when I tried to install Windows guest for KVM/qemu (on Ubuntu 14.04) using Packer.

I used *stable* virtio drivers from Fedora but the installation failed with the same error mesage. Then I found a workaround: when I changed storage type to IDE it worked.

After that I found and tried *latest* (not stable) drivers on Fedora website and the installation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i ended using ide-hd to install the driver once installed I changed it back to scsi-hd and it works fine :D

not sure why you have --enable-kvm and then you have -cpu host,kvm=off this is contracting and I believe qemu will use the last options passed.

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsidev \
-drive if=none,id=hd,file=win.img,format=raw -device ide-hd,drive=hd \
--enable-kvm \
-cdrom Win10_1511_German_x64.iso \
-m 4048 \
-drive file=$HOME/VirtualMachines/virtio-win-0.1.112.iso,id=driveriso,if=none,format=raw \
-device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=driveriso \
-cpu host,kvm=off
```

Comment: Because kvm=off does not disable KVM. [It hides the hypervisor from the guest.](http://serverfault.com/a/727350/126632)